# target a div outside of my Jquery button element

Tags: jquery, html, this, parent, children

I'm trying to target a div outside of my Jquery button element. The way I'm doing it right now is

```
$(this).parent().parent().parent().parent().parent().parent().parent().children(":nth-child(3)").children().children().children(":nth-child(4)");
```

There must be and easier way? The element has a class but there are more identical elements I also need to adjust individually.

Thanks.

CODE:
https://jsfiddle.net/n71mgmgw/

Comment: We need to see context of this code, so please if you can paste fragment of your HTML code here

Comment: Explain the scenario which you are facing and your actual requirement by explaining the DOM structure you are currently having

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/n71mgmgw/

Comment: I'm making a drag and drop form creator. When I submit settings for each dropped element I need it to be apply the changes to the certain element

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe use something like:

```
$(this).closest('.pucontent').find('input.fontSize').val(); // You'll get font size.
// or
$('input.fontSize', $(this).closest('.pucontent')).val();
```

Read about [.closest()](https://api.jquery.com/closest/) and [.find()](https://api.jquery.com/find/) or better read article about [traversing in jQuery](https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/traversing/)

Answer (score 0):

My first suggestion would be to use IDs or the data-XXX attribute to identifie the elements.

Regards

Comment: Is there a way for me to create dynamic ID's using Jquery draggable?